# Redirecting 404s to a page outside the servlet app

Tags: java, servlets

We have several servlet apps living on the same server. Rather than each app maintaining it's own custom 404 page, we'd like them each to forward to the same one at the root of the server.  Adding a configuration like this to the web.xml doesn't work:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/someOtherApp/notFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

It tries redirecting to /myAppName/someOtherApp/notFound.html rather than /someOtherApp/notFound.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure what framework that is, but have you tried `<location>../notFound.html</location>`?

Comment: Where is your `notFound.html` file located?

Comment: updated to specify this is from the web.xml.  These are just war files deployed to either jetty or weblogic (depending on the environment). The framework on top of the servlet spec isn't really important.  Most of these wars serve static files (javascript which calls rest services in other wars). The notFound is served by an app in a different war.  I updated the example to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `location` element of `<error-page>`

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/someOtherApp/notFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

the path must be relative to the root of the application. You can't make it be served by another application.

Some `jetty` docs [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Custom_Error_Pages).

Answer (score 0):

`Location` does *not* redirect, it does a forward. As Sotirios Delimanolis pointed out. It must remain in the webapp (relative to).

Comment: that makes a lot of sense when you word it that way.  You wouldn't want the browser URL to change to some 404 page.  And forwards couldn't work outside the app.  Thanks